# smb.conf file location after make install

Tags: linux, samba

have installed samba 3.5.12 on my CentOS5.1.I have uninstall old samba files from my system using yum and download samba 3.5.12.After decompressing I took following steps

Code:

```
1-   ./autogen.sh 
2-   ./configure
3-    make
4-    make isntall
```

Usually smb.conf file reside on /etc/samba/smb.conf or /usr/local/samba/lib/smb.conf but I does not find any smb.conf file after installation.

I also use but nothing find.

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -qa | grep samba
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in `/usr/local/etc`, or `/usr/local/samba`, or such.

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing the client or the server?  The client doesn't push smb.conf by default.

Have you tried

```
sudo find / | grep smb.conf
```